# C# int stored in double "==" precision problem

Tags: c#, double, int, precision

Here is the simplified code:

```
int i = 1;
double a = i;
double b = i;
```

Is it guarantied that `a == b` is **true**?

Comment: Why not? I would surely like to know why if someone says no!

Comment: Because e.g. 4.0/2.0 != 8.0/4.0 in a general case because of precision problems. There is no any calculations in my problem so the question is if it helps to avoid this problem.

Comment: while technically correct, this is a poor example choice since both those values can be represented exactly by an IEEE 754 double floating point type.

Comment: @codekaizen, yes, you are right, I know that. This is an extremely simplified example.

Comment: (1.0 / 3.0) * 5.0 != 5.0 / 3.0 would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. 32-bit integers can be represented exactly as 64-bit floating point numbers.

Comment: Any references to spec, please?

Comment: I doubt there's anything in the C# spec about this particular case, but if you look at the spec for the IEEE 754 Binary64 format you will see that it uses 52 bits to encode the significand, meaning that it can represent whole numbers up to `2^52 - 1` exactly...or probably more than that. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference) ~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Comment: In any case, even if there were an error in calculation and `i` was some "off" value, you've set `a` and `b` to them, thus they have the same (potentially incorrect) value. It's like asking if `double a = 1; double b = a;`, then does `a == b`? Double precision errors can be nasty, but not like this. Even if you were converting from `long` to `double`, and you lost precision, `a` and `b` would both have the same "incorrect" value -- finding this in the spec is perhaps a more interesting question.

Comment: @Nigel: Implicit Numeric Conversions is the thing that lets us to write "double a = 1" but doesn't say anything about precision.

Comment: @levanovd: "The conversions from int, uint, or long to float and from long to double may cause a loss of precision, but not a loss of magnitude." (from link)

Comment: @Nigel Whatling so that means they round towards + or - infinity rather than truncating like other languages? In C++ `int64_t ( double ( value ) ) < value` if `value` has more than 52 bits in use and the lowest bits set, so the loss of precision causes a loss of magnitude.

Comment: Wow, this got complicated. I don't think the quote from my original link really helped (sorry @levanovd). In the actual C# language spec it goes one further: "The other implicit numeric conversions never lose any information". So int to double loses nothing. @Pete, I don't know how it compares to C++. But following the original example, value is a 32 bit int so it will never have more than 52 bits in use.

Comment: I got some badge about this that reminded me of this answer from over five years ago, and I wanted to respond to my comment about "precision errors can be nasty, but not like this." This doesn't apply to C#, but it's a great read: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323#c109

Answer (score 9):

> Is it guarantied that a == b is true?

Yes. This is because you perform the same conversion twice and given its deterministic behavior you will end up with the same values regardless of the rounding problems.

We can generalize your question though, to:

> Can we perform arithmetic operations on 32-bit integer values encoded in `double` type without precision loose?

The answer for such question is yes as well.

A short justification is that operations on mantissa bits (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) are precise if it is only possible and in case of 32-bit integer values it is possible.

Longer story comes here. As long as your integer value fits in 52 bits of a fraction part called mantissa (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) all calculations on integer values using double will behave completely OK.

This is because your number (say 173 which is `0000010101101b` binary) will be represented as `1.010110100000b*2^7`, which is accurate.

All operations on mantissa are straight forward as long as they fit in mantissa. Rounding on integers occurs when result of a particular operation do not fit in mantissa - eg. you would multiply 40 bits of mantissa by 40 bits of mantissa. Rounding on floating point operations additionally occur when exponents are much different. In this case even a simple addition operation can loose precision because matissas are shifted.

Back to integers encoded in double - even division operation is precise, as long as the result is integer value. So `4.0/2.0 == 8.0/4.0` is also guaranteed to be true.

The problem begins when your number is not integer. But even in this case numbers are guaranteed to be represented precisely if they are a form of `x/2^y` and `x` fits in 52 bits (eg. `3/4` `5/8` `345/1024`). Operations on such numbers are also precise given `y` can be equal for both operands, so even:

```
123456789/1024/1024/1024/1024 == 
(23456789/1024/1024/1024/1024 +
100000000/1024/1024/1024/1024)
```

is guaranteed to be true.

Interesting fact is that you can perform operation on 54 bit signed integers safely. This is because you have additional bit at the beginning whose meaning is encoded by the exponent and one additional bit for a sign. Now -2^53 which would be MIN_INT in case of 54 bit signed integer does not fit the mantissa, but exponent will do the job here with mantissa full of zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can store a (32-bit) integer number in a `double` (64-bit floating-point number) without precision loss.

However, as soon as you perform calculations with your `double`, you will very likely introduce rounding errors, i.e. precision loss. These errors will likely be small enough so that they get rounded away when you cast your `double` value back to `int` — but the error is there, so be aware of it.

**How it's done:** See [this document (***IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers*** by Steve Hollasch)](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for details on how an integer can be stored as a floating-point value.

To summarise (somewhat inaccurately), a floating-point value consists of three parts: A sign bit, a "fraction" part (called the mantissa), and an "exponent" part. They're put together roughly as follows:

*value* = -1 <sup>*sign bit*</sup> × *fraction* × 2 <sup>*exponent*</sup>

You can store the integer value in the "fraction" part of the `double` (which is 52 bits wide, which is more than wide enough for a 32-bit integer. The "exponent" part can just be set to 0, since it's not needed.

Answer (score -2):

I opened Visual Studio, and I tested it.

Here is my code:

```
int i = 5;
double t = i;
double k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //true
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //true
i += 5;
t += 5;
k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //true
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //true
i += (int)Math.Round(5.6);
t += 5.6;
t = (int)Math.Round(t);
k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //true
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //true
i = int.MaxValue - 5438;
t = int.MaxValue - 5438;
k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //true
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //true
i = (int)Math.Round(double.MaxValue);
t = Math.Round(double.MaxValue);
k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //false
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //false
i = (int)Math.Round(double.MaxValue);
t = i;
k = i;
MessageBox.Show((i == t).ToString()); //true
MessageBox.Show((k == t).ToString()); //true
```

The result was two messageboxes saying true.

I guess that concludes that: Yes, you are guaranteed that it will be true.

EDIT: Extended my test a little. The only test returning false were the test at double.MaxValue, but i doubt that you will use that big numbers.

Comment: I downvoted because your conclusion seems quite dangerous to me (even though you're probably right): Just because you've tested *one* simple scenario doesn't mean that this will *always* work. (You've tested 1 case out of 2^32. You're lacking an inductive proof to show that your conclusion is valid for all other integers as well.) -- As soon as you start doing floating-point calculations, you are likely going to introduce rounding errors. Fortunately, for integers, these are so small that they're likely insignificant in most cases.

Comment: **Counter-example:** First, replace the additions with `i /= 2; t /= 2;`. Second, make the casts in your equality test explicit: `i == (int)t` will likely always result in `true`, because the tiny floating-point rounding errors are rounded away. OTOH, `(double)i == t` will result in `false` with the above divisions by 2. -- **Conclusion:** While you can probably *store* an integer in a `double` without loss of precision, this is not true as soon as you start doing *computations* because you introduce rounding errors!

Comment: did you read my counter-example? It gives you a case where your test would not work. Your tests only seem to work because you're relying on the implicit cast from `double` to `int` for variable `t` (and `k`). BUT: `i` and `t` will often be *not* equal! You only "see" equality because you're rounding away the small differences! Try comparing these values as `double`s and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that one before I posted my edit. You are right. But the askers question was if the doubles will be equal if they get their values from the same int, and they will. If you are doing operations on the int and on the double after setting their values, they will no longer be equal, because double can store more complex numbers.